# Best approach for defining sub menu in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could you please suggest the best approach for the following cases:
    Approach for sub menu:
    I have different submenu like submenu1, submenu2 etc(each submenu having its own tab options).
    I want to show up submenu as per the page means divide the submenu according to the open pages.

```
What I am planning for this:
<% content_for(:menu) do %>
    <%=  render :partail => "submanu" %>
<% end %>

and calling that section by <%= yield(:menu) %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something similiar based on a helper method "show menu" and hashes in the controller. In your case I would suggest something like:

```
def show
@menu = [{title: "menu.pages.one", controller: "pages", action: "one"},
{title: "menu.test.two", controller: "test", action: "two"}]
end
```

Then you can combine it with a helper method which display each menu item and create a link like:

```
link_to t(item[:title]), :controller => item[:controller], :action => item[:action]
```

I've used the helper method to create an haml layout foreach link but you can use partials too. So you can create in each controller/method an extendable menu which is self explaining.